# Save ZipArchive to Stream

Tags: c#, .net, zip, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

I am working on a project where i update a ZipArchive and upload it back to server but I can only upload it using a stream.

```
public IActionResult DeleteZippedFile(string path)
{
    //read the zip from stream
    var zip = new ZipArchive(DownloadStream(Request.Cookies["OpenedZipPath"]), ZipArchiveMode.Update);

    //make changes
    zip.Entries.Where(x => x.Name == path).ToList()[0].Delete();

    //i want to convert here <------
    ftp.UploadStream(THESTREAMIWANT)

    //and back to the zip
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(OpenZip));
}
```

How can i save ZipArchive to a stream?

Comment: You can save ziparchiece using by ZipArchive.Save method

Comment: You created the `ZipArchive` using a `Stream` in the first place, so that is the `Stream` you should be using. If you need to reference that object again later then obviously you need to assign it to a variable. If you can't use that particular `Stream` for whatever reason then copy the data from it to another `Stream` first and then create the `ZipArchive` from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is impossible without a third party library, so i used the [Aspose.zip](https://products.aspose.com/zip/) lib. And here is the working code:

```
public IActionResult DeleteZippedFile(string path)
{
    var zip = new Archive(DownloadStream(Request.Cookies["OpenedZipPath"]));
    zip.DeleteEntry(zip.Entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == path));
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    zip.Save(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ftp.UploadStream(ms, Request.Cookies["OpenedZipPath"]);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(OpenZip));
}
```